# Return a list of objects from Controller and Parse the objects in razor c# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a very simple call that I make to an object from my controller. It return a list of objects that have values I need to pull out on a razor form.

Here is the controller code:

```
public List<DocumentSearchResult> Results(string searchString, string location)
    {
        return SharePointRESTDocSearch.SearchResult(location, searchString);
    }
```

This returns a list of SearchResult objects that have these properties on the object:

> DocumentTitle, DocumentPath

In my view I call the controller as follows:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "SharePointSearch"))
{
    <label>Search Term</label>
    <input type="text" id="searchString" name="searchString" />

    <label>SharePoint Location</label>
    <input type="text" id="location" name="location" />
    <input class="button" id="Submit" type="submit" value="Search" />

}
```

I can intercept the code in the controller and there are results coming back.  I just need to know how to return the results from the controller and loop through the results in the razor page to display the information.  I tried this:

```
 @foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <p>Document Title: @item.DocumentTitle</p>
}
```

But I am getting a null error on the Model.  I have no control over the data returned from the SearchResult, I just need to parse the return items and display the results.

thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me how that controller method relates to the view.  That method isn't returning a view at all, so it's not the controller action.  What is the controller action?  How is it calling the method you're showing?  How does it pass the results to the view?

Comment: There is no model for this result, this call is returning a System.Collections.Generic.List of items from the SearchResult

Comment: *"There is no model"* - Well, if you're not sending a model to the view then that would explain why `Model` is `null` in the view.  Where do you try to pass anything to the view?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify my "There is no model" statement, that was wrong.  When I try to return the model I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult to System.Collection.Generic.List<SharePointRESTSearch.DocumentSearchResult>' error.  using this line:

List<DocumentSearchResult> x = SharePointRESTDocSearch.SearchResult(location, searchString);
            return View(x);

Comment: And which line of code gives you this error?  Why are you trying to convert from one type to the other?  Please clarify the question to include the error you're getting and the code which produces the error.

Comment: The line that causes the error is return View(x);  I don't want to necessarily convert from one type to another, I just want to return the list of DocumentSearchResult to the view so I can iterate over them in the razor page and pull out the data I need.  I am new to mvc so I am trying to understand how to return this list to the razor view to iterate in a loop.

Comment: If that's the line causing the error then, according to the error message, you're trying to return a `ViewResult` from a method which has the return type of `List<DocumentSearchResult>`.  As the error states, you can't convert from the former to the latter.  But, again, none of this is in the code in your question.  The error seems to be centered around your controller action method, which you've omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense to me... You should be returning a View and send the list you want to send as the Model.

Like this...

```
public ActionResult Results(string searchString, string location)
{
    List<DocumentSearchResult> model = SharePointRESTDocSearch.SearchResult(location, searchString);
    return View(model);
}
```

Unless I dont understand what the problem is

Comment: Assuming the OP's view name is named Results. Otherwise the OP would have to do `return View("ViewName", model);`

Comment: This worked.  I needed to add the ActionResult and return the view.  Thanks so much!